# Facebook Developer Invitation for a Facebook App not received

Tags: facebook

My friend sent me a developer invitation for a facebook we are supposed develop together. This is what he did.

1. He created the Facebook app
2. He then configured the app name and other settings
3. Then he invited me as Application Developer in the app's settings page. FB shows my name and it shows that "Pending" near my name in the app's settings.

I am an approved facebook developer and I am his friend in FB. Its been 2 days and still I have not got his developer invitation. Am I missing any place in my FB account to see this.

I am not sure what has gone wrong. Please help me to see/get my developer invitation that he sent ? Stuck in this for 2 days.............

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### **UPDATE SEPT 2022:**
Looks like /requests/ is now a 404. New location for invitees to visit and app dev accept invite is https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/requests/

UPDATE FEB 2020:
This issue is still relevant and happens from time to time. If notification is missing, then invited person should navigate to https://developers.facebook.com/requests/ and accept invite there.

Not sure why this got downvoted, I was having the exact same problem the other day. The problem may be that, like me, you're expecting to see a message from Facebook (via notifications) about this. That's not how it works. You will get a developer request, which will show up on your requests panel--this thing, which appears in the right-hand column:

[image]

At the bottom it should say "1 developer request". Click through to that and approve the app, and you should be good to go.

Comment: my friends have invited twice or thrice. i dont see any requests like "1 developer request" in my requests section.

Comment: This did the trick for me, thank you! I would expect more from Facebook...

Comment: This page is a 404 now. The latest location is https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/requests/

Comment: Update Jan 2023. The situation is still as strange as it was in 2012, devs, testers don't have anything anywhere to accept their roles I add. Inclusing the /settings/developer/requests/ page.

Answer (score 13):

I was having issues with the Facebook UI for accepting Developer requests, trying to view them just recursively took me to https://developers.facebook.com/apps?view=app_requests.

Jumping here allowed me to accept the request.
https://www.facebook.com/reqs.php

Answer (score 4):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/requests/ to check your application requests.

Answer (score 2):

This bug in facebook app dev invites continues. :( FB keeps moving the location of the page which you can manually access in order to accept requests.

The latest location as of Sept 2022 is:
https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/requests/

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the request notification you need to login and become a developer on developers.facebook.com